# Error on UIWebView with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, uiwebview

I'm building an ePub reader and I'm loading the html files of every chapter on an UIWebView. When user reaches the end of a chapter, I load on the same webView the next chapter. As I need to execute some jQuery functions in order to create highlights, notes and many extra content, I'm also injecting the jQuery library to the viewer. This is the code I'm using:

```
- (void)loadBook{

    ...

    [self.bookWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:chapterURL]];

    NSString *jQuery = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"jquery" ofType:@"js"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    [self.bookWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jQuery];
}
```

When it loads the first chapter, when `webViewDidFinishLoad:` is called, `$(document).ready`function is called and all my jQuery code works perfectly. When I switch to the following chapter, the `loadBook` function is called again with the new URL but this time `$(document).ready` is not called so when I try to call any  of my functions I get the following error: `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $`

Why it is not loading jQuery library after my first call?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this today and Apple's documentation was to no avail. **In my case, I was loading from local HTML, JS, and CSS files--NOT from a remote web address.** So, this might not do it for you, but it does work for local files.

The following is a workaround. The code is in Swift.

**Method**:

1. In your UIWebViewDelegate, create an Int variable that will be incremented when your data is loaded.
2. Increment it by 1 each time that you load your data (or post the request)
3. In shouldStartLoadWithRequest, check whether the navigation type is "Other" or not: if it is and the counter variable is greater than 1, return false (NO in Objective-C).

This works because the view is instantiated each time it is presented, so the counter is reset to 0.

**Code**:

```
class MyView: ..., UIWebViewDelegate {
  var theCounter = 0
  ...
  func myFunctionWhereILoadTheData() {
    ... load the data (the code in your question)
    theCounter += 1
  }
  ...
  func webView(webView: UIWebView!, shouldStartLoadWithRequest 
          request: NSURLRequest!, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {
     switch navigationType {
       ...
       .Other:
           if theCounter > 1: return false
  }
}
```